# HP Printer does not show ink level via its sofware

Tags: windows-10, printer

Purchased a new printer, installed the software and plugged it in via the USB.

When I try to check ink levels, this is what I get

[image]

Any idea why the estimated levels aren't showing up? The ink tanks are filled to brim currently. Or is it that the gray shaded region is the level indicator?

I was hoping the highlighting would be more vivid.

Comment: Can you post the model number of the printer?

Comment: HP 410 Wireless Ink Tank

Comment: Ask HP Support.

Comment: I googled this for you, I believe the chat support can help you. https://support.hp.com/ph-en/product/hp-ink-tank-wireless-410-series/16180953/troubleshooting